# Facebook app visibility query

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have created a facebook app for my Android application. It was just for tracking downloads of the apps and some other insights.
Is it necessary to make facebook apps  public  if I wanted to use it only for insight of an android application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only you want to use the App, you don´t need to make it public. Putting it public means that you allow other users to use it.